# rhandsontable shiny remove footer

Tags: css, shiny, footer, rhandsontable

I use shiny with rhandsontable and bootstrapPage. 
I want to disable the table footer (show entries and search). 
I tried adding

```
tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: none;}")),
```

in my shinyUI, but it didn't do anything. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get why you wouldn't just use CSS to do this? Instead of pushing it on the page with jQuery(?). Step 1: Make sure tfoot is an element or a class/id. If it's the latter, add `.` or `#`. Step 2: Just add `tfoot {display: none;}` to your CSS file, that should do the job (and remember to add `.` or `#`).

Comment: Unfortunately I am not proficient in css. I use a bootstrap css-file (shinytheme) without any further edit. How could I alter the .css-code in the shiny environment?